# How do I make new row in a tibble with the mean of the 3 previous rows

Tags: r

I have a tibble of data.

```
# A tibble: 41 × 33
   cyc   `A1_Target 1` `A2_Target 1` `B1_Target 1` `B2_Target 1` `B3_Target 1` `B4_Target 1` `C1_Target 1` `C2_Target 1` `C3_Target 1` `C4_Target 1` `D1_Target 1`
   <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 1             0.786         0.860         0.945         0.829          1.70         0.805         0.758          1.93         0.969         0.904         0.514
 2 2             0.792         0.863         0.951         0.833          1.70         0.801         0.776          1.93         0.975         0.905         0.515
 3 3             0.826         0.874         0.965         0.860          1.70         0.801         0.840          1.92         1.01          0.918         0.513
 4 4             0.862         0.903         1.02          0.943          1.73         0.803         0.946          1.93         1.09          0.949         0.515
 5 5             0.921         0.948         1.11          1.08           1.77         0.812         1.11           1.94         1.22          1.01          0.523
 6 6             1.04          1.04          1.25          1.27           1.86         0.842         1.36           1.95         1.41          1.09          0.528
 7 7             1.25          1.17          1.48          1.55           1.98         0.881         1.67           2.00         1.68          1.25          0.544
 8 8             1.52          1.38          1.78          1.86           2.16         0.935         1.98           2.06         1.99          1.47          0.557
 9 9             1.87          1.66          2.11          2.19           2.35         1.04          2.29           2.17         2.31          1.74          0.597
10 10            2.26          1.99          2.41          2.47           2.54         1.20          2.56           2.30         2.60          2.02          0.621
# ℹ 31 more rows
# ℹ 21 more variables: `D2_Target 1` <dbl>, `D3_Target 1` <dbl>, `D4_Target 1` <dbl>, `E1_Target 1` <dbl>, `E2_Target 1` <dbl>, `E3_Target 1` <dbl>,
#   `E4_Target 1` <dbl>, `F1_Target 1` <dbl>, `F2_Target 1` <dbl>, `F3_Target 1` <dbl>, `F4_Target 1` <dbl>, `G1_Target 1` <dbl>, `G2_Target 1` <dbl>,
#   `G3_Target 1` <dbl>, `G4_Target 1` <dbl>, `H1_Target 1` <dbl>, `H2_Target 1` <dbl>, `H3_Target 1` <dbl>, `H4_Target 1` <dbl>, `a3_Target 1` <dbl>,
#   `a4_Target 1` <dbl>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I would like to append a new row at the end of the tibble in which each column contains the average of the 3 rows above it.  I've managed to make the new row that has the average of all rows above it, but have not been able to figure out how to restrict the average to just the last 3 rows.

```
fdata <- fdata %>%
  ungroup %>%
  reframe(cyc = c(cyc, 'plateau'),
            across(where(is.numeric), ~c(., mean(.))))
```

My deisred output is a tibble in which all original rows exist unchanged.  An additional row has been appended to the end, which has a value containing the mean of the previous three rows.  The below shows the output when I take the mean of the entire column instead of the mean of the last three rows in each column.  The desired output will be formatted the same but the value will be only rows 38-40 not rows 1-40

```
38 38              3.97          3.57          3.66          3.42           3.45         3.53          3.52           3.24         3.56          3.43          2.48 
39 39              3.96          3.56          3.65          3.42           3.45         3.54          3.51           3.23         3.58          3.43          2.47 
40 40              3.94          3.57          3.65          3.41           3.44         3.54          3.51           3.24         3.58          3.44          2.47 
41 plateau         3.12          2.83          2.97          2.83           2.98         2.61          2.88           2.87         2.98          2.73          1.73
```

Comment: What would your desired output look like with the above data?

Comment: @jpsmith I've updated my question with my desired output.  Let me know if I can clarify further.

Answer (score 2):

Using the base dataset `anscombe` you can do:

### tidyverse

Here are a few tidyverse options:

```r
df <- anscombe

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

bind_rows(df, colMeans(tail(df, 3)))

# OR

df |>
  add_row(!!! map(df, ~ mean(tail(.x, 3))))

# OR

df %>%
  summarize(across(where(is.numeric), ~ mean(tail(.x, 3)))) %>%
  bind_rows(df, .)
```

### Base R

```r
df[nrow(df) + 1,] <- colMeans(tail(df, 3))
```

Comment: The much-touted superior readability of tidyverse code compared to base R is nowhere to be seen here ...